# Typescript Garbage Collection on Linked List

Tags: typescript, garbage-collection

I am currently learning typescript and tried my hand at implementing a Linked List. I came across a scenario in which I am not sure how references are handled and when the garbage collector is allowed to collect a piece of memory.

Node implementation

```
class Node{
  next: Node | null;
  data: number;

  constructor(data: number){
    this.data = data;
    this.next = null;
  }
}
```

List Implementation

```
class LinkedList {
  head: Node | null;

  constructor(){
    this.head = null;
  }

  // append
  
  // deleteValue
  deleteValue(value: number){
    let prev: Node;
    let curr: Node;
    // loop until curr.data = value
    // < Insert Deletion Code Here >
```

When I am deleting the `curr` node, is it enough to point `prev.next` to `curr.next` thereby eliminating all references to `curr` allowing the garbage collector to capture. Or must I also set `curr = null` ?

Comment: Once the method completes, `curr` is gone, thus removing the last reference to the node.

Comment: @VLAZ thinking about it, `prev` has a reference to the `next` property of `curr`, wouldn't that inhibit garbage collection? The solution might actually involve some intermediate variable.

Comment: When the method finishes, all variables cease to exist. If there are no other references to the objects the variables pointed to, then the objects are eligible for GC.